# Updated new key value pair at every child level in array of object

Tags: javascript

i have array of objects and i want to update value at every nested child level I'm not able to find how to achieve that

Input

```js
let data = [{
    label: 'classA',
    value: 40,
    children: [{
        label: 'classA_sectioA',
        value: 12,
        children: [{
            label: 'classA_sectioA_student1',
            value: 7,
          },
          {
            label: 'classA_sectioA_student2',
            value: 3,
          },
          {
            label: 'classA_sectioA_student3',
            value: 2,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'classA_sectioB',
        value: 15,
        children: [{
            label: 'classA_sectioB_student1',
            value: 7,
          },
          {
            label: 'classA_sectioB_student2',
            value: 3,
          },
          {
            label: 'classA_sectioB_student3',
            value: 5,
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        label: 'classA_sectioC',
        value: 13,
        children: [{
            label: 'classA_sectioC_student1',
            value: 6,
          },
          {
            label: 'classA_sectioC_student2',
            value: 3,
          },
          {
            label: 'classA_sectioC_student3',
            value: 4,
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'classB',
    value: 60,
    children: [{
        label: 'classB_sectioA',
        value: 12,
        children: [{
            label: 'classB_sectioA_student1',
            value: 6,
          },
          {
            label: 'classB_sectioA_student2',
            value: 5,
          },
          {
            label: 'classB_sectioA_student3',
            value: 1,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'classB_sectioB',
        value: 18,
        children: [{
            label: 'classB_sectioB_student1',
            value: 3,
          },
          {
            label: 'classB_sectioB_student2',
            value: 13,
          },
          {
            label: 'classB_sectioB_student3',
            value: 2,
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        label: 'classB_sectioC',
        value: 30,
        children: [{
            label: 'classB_sectioC_student1',
            value: 1,
          },
          {
            label: 'classB_sectioC_student2',
            value: 9,
            children: [{
                label: 'shan',
                value: 4,
              },
              {
                label: 'sk',
                value: 2,
              },
              {
                label: 'tk',
                value: 2,
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            label: 'classB_sectioC_student3',
            value: 20,
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'classC',
    value: 90,
    children: [{
        label: 'classC_sectioA',
        value: 30,
        children: [{
            label: 'classC_sectioA_student1',
            value: 11,
          },
          {
            label: 'classC_sectioA_student2',
            value: 12,
          },
          {
            label: 'classC_sectioA_student3',
            value: 7,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'classC_sectioB',
        value: 20,
        children: [{
            label: 'classC_sectioB_student1',
            value: 1,
          },
          {
            label: 'classC_sectioB_student2',
            value: 16,
          },
          {
            label: 'classC_sectioB_student3',
            value: 13,
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        label: 'classC_sectioC',
        value: 40,
        children: [{
            label: 'classC_sectioC_student1',
            value: 21,
            children: [{
                label: 'shanu',
                value: 22,
                >
                label: 'sk',
                value: 18,
              },
              {
                label: 'tk',
                value: 11,
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            label: 'classC_sectioC_student2',
            value: 12,
          },
          {
            label: 'classC_sectioC_student3',
            value: 7,
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Excepted output

```
let data = [{
    label: 'classA',
    value: 40,
    Radius: 20
    children: [{
        label: 'classA_sectioA',
        value: 12,
        Radius: 40
        children: [{
            label: 'classA_sectioA_student1',
            value: 7,
          },
          {
            label: 'classA_sectioA_student2',
            value: 3,
          },
          {
            label: 'classA_sectioA_student3',
            value: 2,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'classA_sectioB',
        value: 15,
        Radius: 40
        children: [{
            label: 'classA_sectioB_student1',
            value: 7,
            Radius: 60
          },
          {
            label: 'classA_sectioB_student2',
            value: 3,
            Radius: 60
          },
          {
            label: 'classA_sectioB_student3',
            value: 5,
            Radius: 60
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        label: 'classA_sectioC',
        value: 13,
        Radius: 40
        children: [{
            label: 'classA_sectioC_student1',
            value: 6,
            Radius: 60
          },
          {
            label: 'classA_sectioC_student2',
            value: 3,
            Radius: 60
          },
          {
            label: 'classA_sectioC_student3',
            value: 4,
            Radius: 60
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'classB',
    value: 60,
    Radius: 20
    children: [{
        label: 'classB_sectioA',
        value: 12,
        Radius: 40
        children: [{
            label: 'classB_sectioA_student1',
            value: 6,
            Radius: 60
          },
          {
            label: 'classB_sectioA_student2',
            value: 5,
            Radius: 60
          },
          {
            label: 'classB_sectioA_student3',
            value: 1,
            Radius: 60
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'classB_sectioB',
        value: 18,
        Radius: 40
        children: [{
            label: 'classB_sectioB_student1',
            value: 3,
            Radius: 60
          },
          {
            label: 'classB_sectioB_student2',
            Radius: 60
            value: 13,
          },
          {
            label: 'classB_sectioB_student3',
            value: 2,
            Radius: 60
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        label: 'classB_sectioC',
        value: 30,
        Radius: 40
        children: [{
            label: 'classB_sectioC_student1',
            value: 1,
            Radius: 60
          },
          {
            label: 'classB_sectioC_student2',
            Radius: 60
            value: 9,
            children: [{
                label: 'shan',
                value: 4,
                Radius: 80
              },
              {
                label: 'sk',
                value: 2,
                Radius: 80
              },
              {
                label: 'tk',
                value: 2,
                Radius: 80
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            label: 'classB_sectioC_student3',
            value: 20,
            Radius: 60
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'classC',
    value: 90,
    Radius: 20
    children: [{
        label: 'classC_sectioA',
        value: 30,
        Radius: 40
        children: [{
            label: 'classC_sectioA_student1',
            value: 11,
            Radius: 60
          },
          {
            label: 'classC_sectioA_student2',
            value: 12,
            Radius: 60
          },
          {
            label: 'classC_sectioA_student3',
            value: 7,
            Radius: 60
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'classC_sectioB',
        value: 20,
        Radius: 40
        children: [{
            label: 'classC_sectioB_student1',
            value: 1,
            Radius: 60
          },
          {
            label: 'classC_sectioB_student2',
            value: 16,
            Radius: 60
          },
          {
            label: 'classC_sectioB_student3',
            value: 13,
            Radius: 60
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        label: 'classC_sectioC',
        value: 40,
        Radius: 40
        children: [{
            label: 'classC_sectioC_student1',
            Radius: 60
            value: 21,
            children: [{
                label: 'shanu',
                value: 22,
                Radius: 80
              },
              {
                label: 'sk',
                value: 18,
                Radius: 80
              },
              {
                label: 'tk',
                value: 11,
                Radius: 80
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            label: 'classC_sectioC_student2',
            value: 12,
            Radius: 60
          },
          {
            label: 'classC_sectioC_student3',
            value: 7,
            Radius: 60
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

//a new property radius added at every level and it's multiply by 20 with there levels of depth

i tried to update object with recursive function but after certain level i don't know how to do that recursively because i have to hold the index at every level that is the pain point for me

Comment: do you have some more compact data?

Comment: Is there any issues with data set given above

Comment: I have array of data just want to update  or add radius at every nested level

Answer (score 0):

You could map new object with their radius.

```js
const
    data = [{ label: 'classA', value: 40, children: [{ label: 'classA_sectioA', value: 12, children: [{ label: 'classA_sectioA_student1', value: 7 }, { label: 'classA_sectioA_student2', value: 3 }, { label: 'classA_sectioA_student3', value: 2, }] }, { label: 'classA_sectioB', value: 15, children: [{ label: 'classA_sectioB_student1', value: 7 }, { label: 'classA_sectioB_student2', value: 3 }, { label: 'classA_sectioB_student3', value: 5 }] }, { label: 'classA_sectioC', value: 13, children: [{ label: 'classA_sectioC_student1', value: 6 }, { label: 'classA_sectioC_student2', value: 3 }, { label: 'classA_sectioC_student3', value: 4 }] }] }, { label: 'classB', value: 60, children: [{ label: 'classB_sectioA', value: 12, children: [{ label: 'classB_sectioA_student1', value: 6 }, { label: 'classB_sectioA_student2', value: 5 }, { label: 'classB_sectioA_student3', value: 1 }] }, { label: 'classB_sectioB', value: 18, children: [{ label: 'classB_sectioB_student1', value: 3 }, { label: 'classB_sectioB_student2', value: 13 }, { label: 'classB_sectioB_student3', value: 2 }] }, { label: 'classB_sectioC', value: 30, Radius: 40, children: [{ label: 'classB_sectioC_student1', value: 1, Radius: 60 }, { label: 'classB_sectioC_student2', Radius: 60, value: 9, children: [{ label: 'shan', value: 4 }, { label: 'sk', value: 2 }, { label: 'tk', value: 2 }] }, { label: 'classB_sectioC_student3', value: 20 }] }] }, { label: 'classC', value: 90, children: [{ label: 'classC_sectioA', value: 30, Radius: 40, children: [{ label: 'classC_sectioA_student1', value: 11 }, { label: 'classC_sectioA_student2', value: 12 }, { label: 'classC_sectioA_student3', value: 7 }] }, { label: 'classC_sectioB', value: 20, children: [{ label: 'classC_sectioB_student1', value: 1 }, { label: 'classC_sectioB_student2', value: 16 }, { label: 'classC_sectioB_student3', value: 13 }] }, { label: 'classC_sectioC', value: 40, children: [{ label: 'classC_sectioC_student1', value: 21, children: [{ label: 'shanu', value: 22 }, { label: 'sk', value: 18 }, { label: 'tk', value: 11 }] }, { label: 'classC_sectioC_student2', value: 12 }, { label: 'classC_sectioC_student3', value: 7 }] }] }],
    addRadius = Radius => ({ children, ...o }) => children
        ? { ...o, Radius, children: children.map(addRadius(Radius + 20)) }
        : { ...o, Radius },
    result = data.map(addRadius(20));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `map()` over each object in the array
2. Use a helper function, `addRadius` that accepts an object and

   1. If there are `children`, recursive call the same function to add `radius`
   2. Add radius to the object
   3. return object

```js
let data = [{label: 'classA', value: 40, children: [{label: 'classA_sectioA', value: 12, children: [{label: 'classA_sectioA_student1', value: 7, }, {label: 'classA_sectioA_student2', value: 3, }, {label: 'classA_sectioA_student3', value: 2, } ] }, {label: 'classA_sectioB', value: 15, children: [{label: 'classA_sectioB_student1', value: 7, }, {label: 'classA_sectioB_student2', value: 3, }, {label: 'classA_sectioB_student3', value: 5, } ], }, {label: 'classA_sectioC', value: 13, children: [{label: 'classA_sectioC_student1', value: 6, }, {label: 'classA_sectioC_student2', value: 3, }, {label: 'classA_sectioC_student3', value: 4, } ] } ] }, {label: 'classB', value: 60, children: [{label: 'classB_sectioA', value: 12, children: [{label: 'classB_sectioA_student1', value: 6, }, {label: 'classB_sectioA_student2', value: 5, }, {label: 'classB_sectioA_student3', value: 1, } ] }, {label: 'classB_sectioB', value: 18, children: [{label: 'classB_sectioB_student1', value: 3, }, {label: 'classB_sectioB_student2', value: 13, }, {label: 'classB_sectioB_student3', value: 2, } ], }, {label: 'classB_sectioC', value: 30, children: [{label: 'classB_sectioC_student1', value: 1, }, {label: 'classB_sectioC_student2', value: 9, children: [{label: 'shan', value: 4, }, {label: 'sk', value: 2, }, {label: 'tk', value: 2, } ] }, {label: 'classB_sectioC_student3', value: 20, } ] } ] }, {label: 'classC', value: 90, children: [{label: 'classC_sectioA', value: 30, children: [{label: 'classC_sectioA_student1', value: 11, }, {label: 'classC_sectioA_student2', value: 12, }, {label: 'classC_sectioA_student3', value: 7, } ] }, {label: 'classC_sectioB', value: 20, children: [{label: 'classC_sectioB_student1', value: 1, }, {label: 'classC_sectioB_student2', value: 16, }, {label: 'classC_sectioB_student3', value: 13, } ], }, {label: 'classC_sectioC', value: 40, children: [{label: 'classC_sectioC_student1', value: 21, children: [{label: 'shanu', value: 22, },{label: 'sk', value: 18, }, {label: 'tk', value: 11, } ] }, {label: 'classC_sectioC_student2', value: 12, }, {label: 'classC_sectioC_student3', value: 7, } ] } ] } ];

const addRadius = (to, depth = 1) => {
    if (to.children) {
        to.children = to.children.map(e => addRadius(e, depth + 1));
    }
    return { radius: (depth * 20), ...to };
};

const res = data.map(o => addRadius(o));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple code should do the job

```
const listItems = [
  {
    label: "classA",
    value: 40,
    children: [
      {
        label: "classA_sectioA",
        value: 12,
        children: [
          {
            label: "classA_sectioA_student1",
            value: 7
          },
          {
            label: "classA_sectioA_student2",
            value: 3
          },
          {
            label: "classA_sectioA_student3",
            value: 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

function mapRecursive(items = [], depth = 1) {
  let newList = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const item = { ...items[i] };

    const children = item?.children ?? [];

    if (!!children.length) {
      const newItems = mapRecursive(children, depth + 1);
      item.children = newItems;
    }

    newList.push({
      ...item,
      radius: (item.radius ?? 0) + depth * 20,
      depth
    });
  }

  return newList;
}

console.log("mapRecursive", mapRecursive(listItems));
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Using plain recursion and setting the property `radius` on each node visited.

As a side note, since I used a named function expression to have the recursion right, it should be said that such strategy is allowed also when setting a variable with it like:

```
const f = function internalname(i=0){
 console.log(i);
 if (i<10) internalname(++i);
}
f();
```

And one last remark is that actually the expected output you showed didn't have the radius property set in the most inner children of the very first object in the array. ***I'm considering it an unfortunate typo and expecting it to be set also in those cases***.

```js
let data = [{/*...*/}];

//set the radius property to the passed nodes based on the depth
function setRadius(depth, ...nodes){  
  //for each node
  nodes.forEach( node => {
    node.radius = depth*20;
    //if there's the property children set for this node,
    if('children' in node)
      //set the radius to all the children with depth+1
      setRadius(depth+1, ...node.children);
  });  
}

setRadius(1, ...data);

console.log(data);
```